# Is there an easier way to copy a triangle-shaped data to another worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy this data from "Workbook 1" (I purposely scribble out the data):
[image]

And paste it to "Workbook 2" by using VBA.
[image]

This is my current code:

```
   Sub CopyPaste()
        Workbook 1 = "C:\5 File\Workbook 1.xlsb"
        Workbook 2 = "C:\5 File\Workbook 2.xlsb"
        Workbooks.Open (Workbook 1)
        Workbooks.Open (Workbook 2)
        Workbooks(Workbook 1).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("AO5:AO21").Copy
        Workbooks(Workbook 2).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("C6:C22").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(Workbook 1).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("AP5:AO20").Copy
        Workbooks(Workbook 2).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("D6:D21").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(Workbook 1).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("AQ5:AQ19").Copy
        Workbooks(Workbook 2).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("E6:E20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        'And so on
   End Sub
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Er, copy the entire range in one go i.e if the data below the triangle is blank? `Range("AD2004:BD2021").Copy` ?

Comment: There are also different ways to loop through the process, depending on how consistent the ranges are. But since we are using absolute references, it would have to be rather consistent. But copying it all in one go would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As you only copy values, it is not necessary to use `Copy` & `PasteSpecial`, just assign the values.

The following routine will copy a triangle of data row by row:

```
Sub copyTriangle(sourceRange As Range, destRange As Range, numberOfRows As Long)
    
    Dim row As Long
    For row = numberOfRows To 1 Step -1
        destRange.Offset(numberOfRows - row, 0).Resize(1, row).Value = _
            sourceRange.Offset(numberOfRows - row, 0).Resize(1, row).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

In your case, you would call it with

```
CopyTriange(Workbooks(Workbook1).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("AO5"), _
            Workbooks(Workbook2).Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("C6"), 
            17
```

Answer (score 0):

### Triangle vs Rectangle (Square)

- Since the cells in the 'bottom-right triangle' are empty, it would be more efficient to copy the whole rectangle which is a square in this particular case.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()
        
    ' Source
    Const sPath As String = "C:\5 File\Workbook 1.xlsb"
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "AO5"
    ' Destination
    Const dPath As String = "C:\5 File\Workbook 2.xlsb"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "C6"
    ' Source
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim rgSize As Long
    With swb.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
        Set srg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        rgSize = srg.Row - .Row + 1
        Set srg = .Resize(rgSize, rgSize)
    End With
    ' Destination
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dPath)
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dwb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(rgSize, rgSize)
    ' Copy by Assignement
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    ' Close
    'swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' read from
    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True ' written to
   
End Sub
```